# ui-grid get the current column (field) name from inside a custom sorting algorithm?

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Once you define custom sorting for a column like in  [Github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Sorting) and [UI-Grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef)

How can you access the column from inside the algorithm?

```
var myAwesomeSortFn = function(a,b, rowA, rowB, direction){

       // "Need to access the name (field) of column being sorted here";
        var column = "No Idea"

       console.log("sorting by column " + column );

        if (a == b) return 0;
        if (a < b) return -1;
        if (a > b) return 1;


    };
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling `myAwesomeSortFn`?

Comment: See the Github link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following...

```
{ field: 'lastName', displayName: 'Last Name', sortingAlgorithm: MyService.getSortingAlgorithm('lastName') },
```

Then define in a service (or in your scope if you prefer)

```
getSortingAlgorithm: function (columnName) {
    return function(a, b, rowA, rowB, direction) {
        console.log("sorting by column " + columnName);

        if (a == b) return 0;
        if (a < b) return -1;
        if (a > b) return 1;
    };  
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing, it works, but also means lots of time when you have over 40 columns, plus the maintainability cost when fields change.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted since it seems to be the only way to do it without modifying ui-grid, which we ended up doing to expose the column.